# Enable/disable checkbox of sap.ui.table.TreeTable depending on model data

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I use SAP UI5 version 1.52.6.
Depending on model data, I would like to enable/disable a sap.ui.table.TreeTable view accordingly.  see view:

```
<t:TreeTable id="tree">
    <t:columns>
        <t:Column>
            <t:label>
                <Label text="{i18n>serviceName}"/>
            </t:label>
            <t:template>
                <Label text="{Description}" />
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
    </t:columns>
    <t:Column>
        <Label text="{i18n>serviceTechName}"/>
        <t:template templateShareable="true">
            <Text text="{Id}"/>
        </t:template>
    </t:Column>
</t:TreeTable>
```

Problem is that there is no method to enable the checkbox in TreeTable, see a similar topic being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43252472/sap-ui-table-table-row-selecter-disable-in-sapui5):

How can one disable a checkbox, e.g. if model data of the row has a property called "Enabled" of true? I twould ry to avoid too much jQuery here but did not manage to grab the right attribute of the row anyways.

Comment: I don't wanna discourage you but I've been worked on this before and after a few days and lost some of my hair I've decided to use my own checkboxes instead of tree/tree table's selection mode. Not just this, tree/tree table also have problems when handling sub items selections. So... good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to handle the rowSelectionChange event of the table and deselect the not desired rows explicitly, and maybe combine this with a message to the user to inform about the fact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Sounds like a way, but IMHO in matter of UX this is too complex as I want to reduce interaction with an user.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for disable checkbox in sap.ui.table

```js
 oTable.addDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function () {
     var count = this.getVisibleRowCount();
     var selectAllId = "#" + this.getId() + "-selall";
     $(selectAllId).addClass("disabledbutton");
     for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      var columId = "#" + this.getId() + "-rowsel" + i;
      $(columId).addClass("disabledbutton");
     }
    }
   }, oTable);
   oTable.rerender();
```

```css
.disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```