# sap.ui.table.TreeTable: Set Certain Check Boxes Invisible

Tags: sapui5

I am having trouble to find a way to remove or set the visibility to `false` for the checkbox of specific rows from a [sap.ui.table.TreeTable](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.TreeTable).

For example, for the table below, I would like to disable or remove the checkbox for *subitem1-1*, *subitem1-2*, and *subitem2-1*.

[image]

Please refer to the following for code sample:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
  sap.ui.require([
    "sap/ui/table/TreeTable",
    "sap/ui/table/Column",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
  ], function(TreeTable, Column, JSONModel) {
    const treeTable = new TreeTable({
      columns: [
        new Column({
          label: "Name",
          template: "name",
        }),
      ],
      selectionMode: "MultiToggle",
      enableSelectAll: true,
    });
    treeTable.setModel(new JSONModel({
      root: {
        name: "root",
        description: "root description",
        checked: true,
        0: {
          name: "item1",
          description: "item1 description",
          checked: true,
          0: {
            name: "subitem1-1",
            description: "subitem1-1 description",
            checked: true,
          },
          1: {
            name: "subitem1-2",
            description: "subitem1-2 description",
            checked: true,
          },
        },
        1: {
          name: "item2",
          description: "item2 description",
          checked: true,
          0: {
            name: "subitem2-1",
            description: "subitem2-1 description",
            checked: true,
          },
        },
      },
    })).bindRows("/root").placeAt("content");
  });
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-preload="async"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-xx-async="true"
  data-sap.ui-xx-waitForTheme="true"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Any help or suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable/disable checkbox of sap.ui.table.TreeTable depending on model data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428991/enable-disable-checkbox-of-sap-ui-table-treetable-depending-on-model-data)